# Closing fancybox after login, and send content to parent page. - ASP.NET C# page

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, fancybox, modal-dialog

I would really like to make this question very clear for all of us.
I have a website in ASP.NET (C#) that has a long login procedure, two screens before it logs you in.
I am trying to use Fancybox (modal) to do this login procedure. It's the prettiest thing ever.
I am currently using it with the iFrame option. I write the username, then the password and it validates if its ok or not. If I am logged in, the resulting page appears inside of the modal window, and I will like to send it to the parent window and close the fancybox automatically after logging in.

I have used the "$.fancybox.close();" function but it seems to not work. 
Can you guys give me a hint on how to do this well ? It's in c# asp.net

Thank you.

Comment: how did you use $.fancybox.close(); please try to use it like this $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
                $.fancybox.close();
            });

Comment: Did you get your problem solved?

Comment: Yes Arie, thanks a lot for asking. I just added the solved checkmark in the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use register this client script on successful  login

```
Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("sdfs6s6", "<script> parent.location ='Welcome.aspx';parent.$.fancybox.close();</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for `parent.$.fn.fancybox.close();`

Take a look at this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/1fc03bb70e370a41) in the Fancybox Group, which pretty much discusses your problem.